# ListCollectionView CustomSort 2 conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listcollectionview

I have a ListCollectionView in my ViewModel which I bind it to a ListBox. Let's say I have a collection of strings, where I first want to sort them by string length, then by alphabetical order. How should I do it?

Currently I managde to sort it by length using CustomSort by implementing my own IComparer class, but how can I do it such that it is also in alphabetical order for the strings with the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use LINQ to do that:

```
List<string> list = GetTheStringsFromSomewhere();
List<string> ordered = list.OrderBy(p => p.Length).ThenBy(p => p).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

You mentioned [`CustomSort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.customsort(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SortDescription`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.sortdescription.sortdescription(v=vs.100).aspx) in your comment.
I think (untested) you should be able to achieve the same result by rolling your own Comparer:

```
public class ByLengthAndAlphabeticallyOrderComparer : IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y)
    {
        var stringX = x as string;
        var stringY = y as string;

        int lengthDiff = stringX.Length - stringY.Length;           
        if (lengthDiff !=)
        {
            return lengthDiff < 0 ? -1 : 1; // maybe the other way around -> untested ;)
        }

        return stringX.Compare(stringY);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
_yourListViewControl.CustomSort = new ByLengthAndAlphabeticallyOrderComparer();
```

Comment: I'm actually expecting to use either SortDescription or CustomSort, so that I do not have to always sort it when the collection changes.

Comment: I've updated my main post. I have a ListCollectionView which i bind to a ListBox ItemsSource. i can drag items in and out of the ListBox, so the collection can change, and whenever the collection changes I want it to be ordered as how I wanted. If I use LINQ, I will always need to re-order it whenever the collection changes. So is there any way I can use SortDescription or CustomSort, so that the UI can automatically sort for me when the collection changes.